# How to generate a 32bit random password using printable characters?

Tags: java

I need a function that will generate a 32bit random password using all printable characters in java

So far, I have

```
Random().ints(10, 33, 123).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i)).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

How to ensure this is 32bit and contains all printable chars?

Comment: Why you just don't encrypt them and that's all?

Comment: What does “32bit” mean?  32 bits of entropy?

Answer (score -4):

32bits are equal to 4 Bytes, which are 4 characters. "All printable characters" can vary drastically according to your encoding: ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc'...
so first you must choose your encoding scheme, then generate a 4 byte array, and turn it into a string while specifying your encoding as a parameter to the String() constructor.

byte in java goes from -128 to 127. so generate 4 bytes, offset them to the value of the first character in your encoding, while taking care of the encoding's upper boundaries as well, put them all in an array and transform to String.